# child process error: Error: channel closed - node + atom

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I am relatively new to Node. I am using Atom and the following error message keeps popping up over and over again:

```
child process error: Error: channel closed
```

Additionally, there have been a couple of times my page has become non-responsive (not sure they are related but believe there is a high likelihood).

What are the steps one would take to track down the cause of this error in order to resolve it?

Hoping the SO community can help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to see if you have the 'atom-ternjs' package installed. I have it installed on Atom 1.8.0 on OS X 10.11.5 and am seeing this error quite often recently. Disable this plugin if you have it installed and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Yes - I did have atom-ternjs installed, and when I disabled it the issue did go away. However, I did like how atom-ternjs would let me know how many arguments and the description of the arguments of a function as I was writing js. Any suggestions for any other packages that might do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Not really a permanent solution, but I found if you "restart" the ternjs server the errors go away (at least for a little while)

[image]